# How to use Bolt events with the newer Slack API manifests?

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm building a Slack App using Bolt and I've got the basics working using Socket Mode. The docs say that socket mode apps are [not allowed in the public directory](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/socket), which I do want my App in when it's ready. I've now turned off socket mode and got ngrok working as described [here](https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/tutorials/local-development). Slack was able to validate the url anyway.

But what's not working is a slash command. The manifest editor says the url is required for a slash command, but how does that line up with bolt? Are there better docs for non-socket-mode somewhere? It seems like every example of using bolt says "let's use socket mode, it's easy".

Manifest portion:

```
slash_commands:
  - command: /sb
   url: https://[my url].ngrok.io/slack/command
```

Sample code:

```
const { App } = require('@slack/bolt');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const boltApp = new App({
    signingSecret: config.slackApp.signingSecret,
    token: config.slackApp.token,
    endpoints = '/'
});

app.use('/slack/events', boltApp.receiver.router);
```

[Bolt](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/tutorial/getting-started)

[Slack App Manifests](https://api.slack.com/reference/manifests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working with a combination of the following:

- setting every url in the manifest (slash_commands, event_subscriptions, interactivity) to https://foo.ngrok.io/slack/
- attaching Bolt to an existing Express App, attempting to follow [this PR](https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-js/pull/870) to use `app` and/or `router` config prop on `ExpressReceiver`, but strangely what worked was putting the express app into the `router`
- setting up Bolt like below

Example Code:

```
const expressApp = express();
...
const boltReceiver = new ExpressReceiver({
  router: expressApp, 
  signingSecret: SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
  endpoints: '/slack'
});

const boltApp = new App({
  token: SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
  receiver: boltReceiver,
  appToken: SLACK_APP_TOKEN,
  socketMode: false,
});
```